# Using sessionAttributes in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill and not quite sure if I am using `sessionAtrributes` correctly. I know `sessionAttributes` are used to carry-forward a session's data to next invocation. 
So I have these two intents

1) `ListToDoItem`

- In this intent my skill will look into a database and list out the
  to-do items  stored in the database. After listing the items, Alexa
  will go on to say "do you want me to list detailed info on these
  to-do items?", to handle this I will pass the items retrieved in the
  previous session as `sessionAttributes`. When asked to list detailed
  info on the items, I will extract the previously forwarded
  `sessionAtrributes` and compose a detailed speech response.
- So for this intent I have to sample utterances

  - list my to-do items
  - yes

The utterance 'yes' will be used so that the `sessionAttributes` can be extracted to create a detailed speech response.

2) `ListDoneItems`

This intent will be used to list out completed items. It is similar to the previous intent, the only difference being, this intent will list out completed items.

For this intent will have 2 sample utterances

- list my completed items
- yes

Like before it has an 'yes' to generate a detailed speech response based on the sessionAttributes.

But the problem I have is that when I reply 'yes' to the `ListDoneItems` intent's 'Do you want me to list the completed items'?, the next intent request generated is of type `ListToDoItems` instead of `ListDoneItems`, even though I have set `shouldEndSession` to `false` in my skill response. This is happening because there is a crossover between sample utterances between my intents. So is having similar intents in different intents wrong? How to design interaction model to create a multi-turn dialog in order to use in `sessionAttributes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be of use to someone searching for answer.

Basically in the sample utterance you should not include phrases for your re-prompts; i.e. in my case I should not add 'yes' as an utterance. Instead I should be using `Amazon.YesIntent`.

When using `Amazon.YesIntent`, you should maintain a state machine in your `SessionAttributes` pointing to the last invoked intent. For example if two or more of your intents have a possible case where the user response could invoke a `YesIntent`, you should store the last invoked intent name and the associated session data in the `SessionAttributes`. So in the function which handles the `YesIntent`, you should check the state of your previous invocations and delegate to control to the corresponding intent handler.

In my case I will store previously invoked intent name as key and its associated data as it's value in the `session.attributes`;

```
   "session": {
        "new":"false",
        "sessionId": "sessionId",
        "application": {
          "applicationId": "applicationId"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "PreviousIntent": {
             "PreviousIntentData"
        }
    }
```

In the function which handles `YesIntent`, check the for the previous state (`session.attributes.PreviousIntent`) and delegate the control to the function which handles that intent.